# How to easily send my google password to my android tablet?

Tags: google-account, nexus-7, data-transfer, copy-paste

I have a Nexus 7 I haven't used in ages, it no longer remembers my Google account info. The password to my google account is stored on my Mac via KeyChain (it is a long and random character password). Is there any way for me to send this password to the tablet over bluetooth/usb? I tried creating a txt file and putting it in the downloads folder on the tablet but it does not see the file.

I am not able to download any apps to this tablet without this password, so I can only use the apps that are loaded with android.

Comment: Do you have a file manager on the tablet?

Comment: Or an app called "files"

Comment: @ABochur I don't see any app called files. This N7 is running Lolipop btw (the latest official OS it supports)

Comment: "I tried creating a txt file and putting it in the downloads folder on the tablet but it does not see the file." Can u explain that part? What method did you use, and where is this Download folder?

Comment: @ABochur I used the file transfer program, it showed one of the folders on the tablet was called Downloads - there's a Downloads app on the tablet

Comment: so you tried using using Bluetooth to transfer the file, or did you use something else?

Comment: @ABochur usb. I'm not sure how I'd do it via bluetooth. Is there some magical built in facility for sending and receiving things from a Mac via bluetooth similar to AirDrop?

Comment: not sure about Mac, but allot of Microsoft computers, have Bluetooth capability.

Comment: It seems like without Bluetooth or a file manager, or wifi, your best option might be to simply read of the code, and enter it into the tablet. I mean, how long can it be?